# Allow own TestContext class to inject different connections Strings inVisual Studio Unit Test Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mbunit, data-driven-tests

In MBUnit I can annotate my Test class with a Factory and multiple getter returning an oracle/sql/mysql connection string which can be obtained by every test method in the test class.

How can I do this with the Unit Test Project for Visual Studio 2010?

e.g. I am not allowed to inherit from TestContext and pass that object to my ClassInit method?

```
[ClassInitialize()]
public static void MyClassInitialize(MyContextDerivedFromTextContext testContext) 
{

}
```

I do not want to hardcode-annotate my TestMethods with such an attribute:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=STM;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False", "CustomerTable", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add test logic here
            //
        }
```

I want this:

```
public void TestMethod1(String testconnectionStringOracleORMySQLORMSSQLetc...)
{
    //
    // TODO: Add test logic here
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out for some disappointment.  MSTest supports data driven tests as you've already shown but [it sucks](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/03/mstest-sucks-for-unit-tests.html) compared to other test frameworks.

The only approach I can think of that might do what you want is to store your connection strings in an XML file and that as a data source for your MSTest tests to set up the connection and then do whatever else it is you need to do.

Comment: We use the the free/community version of MBUnit but it behaves very buggy and has a bad IDE integration. Do you maybe know NUnit is the integration better into VS2010?

Comment: VS2010 only supports MSTest directly (Visual Studio 11 will enable 3rd party frameworks to be used as well). Personally I use TestDriven.Net which has MBUnit support.  I'm pretty sure Gallio/MBUnit v3 has a ReSharper plugin as well.

Comment: Why do you mention ReSharper?

Comment: ReSharper has it's own test runner for executing tests within Visual Studio.  It's used by a lot of developers and might be an option you could look at.

Comment: thanks but I need a free/open source tool :) You tried NUnit?

Comment: Yes, NUnit and XUnit as as well.  They both support data driven tests but neither has integration with the Visual Studio shell.  They both have external test runners.

Comment: So if you tried XUnit which seems the successor of NUnit can It satisfy my requirements by injecting a connection string into a test method?

Comment: If you pass it in as a data driven test (a [Theory] in XUnit) it  should work perfectly well.

Comment: I searched for theory xunit connection string and got really bad google results. I guess I will open another question I want to stick to MBUnit as we use it in the company too ;-). I will put my other MBUnit v2 migration to V3 question here too if you are still in the mood to answer it ;-)

Comment: There it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348536/migration-from-mbunit-v2-to-v3-and-the-providerfactory-is-gone